# Optimizing Query in mysql

Tags: mysql

i've been scratching my head over the past hours to find an optimization for a  query which seems to cost a lot of time:

```
SELECT d.deviceID ,e.latitude, e.longitude,MAX(e.timestamp) as timestamp 
FROM Device as d INNER JOIN EventData as e ON d.deviceID=e.deviceID 
WHERE e.accountID='$account' AND e.timestamp<=$time AND (e.deviceID IN (SELECT deviceID FROM DeviceList WHERE accountID='$account')) 
GROUP BY (e.deviceID);
```

so i'm querying a set of devices and for each device the last associated event.
     Note that **$account/$time** are variables obtained from a $_POST.
***EDIT : Tables structure :***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Device` (
      `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
      `equipmentType` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      `description` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL

);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DeviceList` (
  `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `groupID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EventData` (
  `accountID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `statusCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpsAge` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `speedKPH` double DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: have you done an `explain` on the query?

Comment: show the tables structure

Comment: @OliverQueen i ran it and it shows 3 rows 0: {0: "1", 1: "PRIMARY", 2: "d", 3: "ALL", 4: null, 5: null, 6: null, 7: null, 8: "498",…}
1: {0: "1", 1: "PRIMARY", 2: "e", 3: "ref", 4: "PRIMARY", 5: "PRIMARY", 6: "68",…}
2: {0: "2", 1: "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY", 2: "DeviceList", 3: "ref", 4: "PRIMARY", 5: "PRIMARY"

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `Device` table at all.  Also, an IN [subquery] can be avoided with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT
  e.eviceID,
  e.atitude,
  e.ongitude,
  MAX(e.timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM EventData e
JOIN DeviceList d
  ON e.deviceID = d.deviceID
WHERE e.deviceID   = :account
  AND e.timestamp <= :time
GROUP BY deviceID;
```

Also, you should be using prepared statements instead of putting user-controlled values into a query, but that's a separate topic.

Comment: How does that include / factor in this part of the query: `AND (e.deviceID IN (SELECT deviceID FROM DeviceList WHERE accountID='$account')) 
GROUP BY (e.deviceID);`?

Comment: @cale_b - Fair enough.  I assumed that `DeviceList` and `EventData` both had the same `deviceID` values, but that may not be the case.  Either way, the `Devices` table isn't actually providing value here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mr-llama , but i will need the Device table because of some informations stored on it. i'm guessing the problem is in that the query gets all rows of EventData then apply the MAX aggregate, is there any way of getting the last Event of each device without getting all the rows (Note that EventData has a huge amount of data for each device)

Comment: @abdessamadelouardi - What is your query getting from `Device` that it's not already getting from `DeviceList`?  The only column I see you fetch from it is `deviceID` which you could get from `DeviceList` instead.

Comment: @Mr.Llama i'm getting the device description, and from the DeviceList i need to get all the devices for each groupID

Comment: @abdessamadelouardi - The query in your question does not.  Can you update your question with the *actual* query you're using?